# Rescaling many images which are scaled with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, scaling

In a LaTeX document I have about 70 images which are scaled using the graphicx-package and
`\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{foo.pdf}`

where the scaling factor varies. Now I would like to rescale them all with a common factor, like

```
\newcommand*{\factor}{0.75}
\includegraphics[scale=\factor * 0.8]{foo.pdf}
```

except that is no LaTeX syntax. Can anyone provide a smart solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
\includegraphics[scale=\factor , scale= 0.8]{foo.pdf}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That was quite a bit more elementary to solve than I anticipated.

Comment: I would have thought `[scale=0.8, scale=\factor]`!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides in an ideal world (not this one, admittedly) multiplication is commutative.

Comment: I wonder if you could explain this a bit: it seems entirely non-intuitive to me (keys normally override each other, so I'd expect the scale here to be 0.8 not 0.8 times `\factor`).

Comment: @JosephWright includegraphics keys don't overight they are cumulative and read left to right, mainly so that `[height=1cm,angle=90]` makes something 1cm _wide_ but `[angle=90,height=1cm]` makes something 1cm _high_ the fact that you can use two `scale` is an artifact of the implementation (and not something I've done before this answer I suspect:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Like I say, I think an edit for this would be useful. I know about the business with heights and angles, but didn't know that `scale` would apply twice. With most commands taking a keyval list the approach is that setting the keys saves the settings in some place (a bunch of macros), then those settings apply in one shot. So the common case is that setting a key twice means the first one is ignored and only the second applies.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `fp` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\FPset\Factor{0.75}
\FPeval\Scale{round(Factor*0.8:2)}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=\Scale]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```